# GITLAB-CI: only deploy to DEV if pom version is a snapshot or its a git tag

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am deploying a WAR file built by maven to tomcat using gitlab pipeline.

I would like to deploy to DEV only if the version is a snapshot or commit was a git tag. I have tried using **rules** and **only/except**

I have this at the moment:

```
Deploy to DEV:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    environment:
        name: DEV
        on_stop: Undeploy from DEV
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

This kind of works, the part that it only deploys if a tag has been committed. But how do I also make sure that it is a snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

As written in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#environment-variables-expressions), the main difficulty is:

> Each expression provided is evaluated before a pipeline is created.

So I don't think we can use a `WAR_VERSION` environment variable to have the pipeline to create (or not) a "Deploy to DEV" job. So a possible workaround could be something like:

```
.xmllint:
  image: "registry.gitlab.com/ebaque/spring-sample/alpine-xmllint:latest"

Deploy to DEV:
  stage: deploy
  extends: .xmllint
  script: 
    - WAR_VERSION=$(cat pom.xml | sed '2 s/xmlns=".*"//g' | xmllint --xpath 'string(//project/version)' -)
    - if ! [[ $WAR_VERSION =~ .*SNAPSHOT ]] || [[ -z $CI_COMMIT_TAG ]]; then exit 0; fi
    - ...
```

We can leverage `xmllint` to parse the `pom.xml` file and get the `version` value. Then we can use regex to check whether this string has `SNAPSHOT` in it. `xmllint` was not working with the namespace in the `pom.xml`, so I had to strip its value before parsing the file.

If it does not (or if this is not a `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`), then we exit the job, or we show a message so that the deployment does not fail silently (up to you at this point). This not great, as the job is always created, but it's one way of doing it.

FYI, Here the Dockerfile I wrote for the image used in the example:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache libxml2 libxml2-utils bash
```

The only thing I didn't test here is the `|| [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG ]]`, so you may need to fix this part of the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I really appreciate it. 
This would create the job though. I would like the job not be created if the version isn't a snapshot or it is not tagged.

Comment: also, can I use the "pre" stage instead of a job in build stage?

Comment: and can I not use variables: instead of exporting bash variables?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution suggestion doesn't work. No new jobs are created even if it is a snapshot!

Comment: @Marci-man: it might be late to say that, but unfortunately there's no way to fill variables (in variables section) capturing command outputs (`cat pom.xml | grep...`), because commands can only run inside jobs, where it's late because you can't prevent their creations checking variable values, like pom.xml version tag, and so. Gitlab could provide simple file parsing as a way to fill variables, since they seem to not be interested allowing arbitrary commands to run in variable section (they can't measure Runner time usage there, but only when a job is launched).