# How to stop a gitlab-ci job based on a condition?

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to evaluate in my `gitlab_ci` pipeline if the current `java` project is to build with a `SNAPSHOT` dependency inside the `maven` `pom.xml`:

Like so: `grep -q "SNAPSHOt" pom.xml && echo 1`

Question: how could I integrate this into a ci pipeline so that the pipeline does not even execute if this condition is true?

`gitlab_ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:20
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn package...
```

Where would I add that sort of condition check, and how could I then let the full job fail?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62414757/9047625

This answer will most probably help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
before_script:
  - grep -q "SNAPSHOT" pom.xml && exit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want the pipeline to run only based on some condition you can use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules).
2. if you want the pipeline to run and then fail when some condition is
   not satisfied you can just check the condition in `script` and then
   use `exit some_non_zero number`.

eg:

```yaml
test job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - | 
        if [ 1 == 1 ]
        then
          exit 1
        fi
```

Here for condition i have used `1==1`.

Comment: If you need some more help with this feel free to reply back with details on what you need.

Comment: I don't think so. Rules are to define a condition *when* to run a job. They have no exit codes. I'm looking for a way to let the job fail in case of a certain condition.

Comment: no i meant the exit code as another option. I have updated the answer with more details so its clear.